# nginx doesn't work after reinstall?

Tags: nginx, debian, phusion-passenger, debian-wheezy

I really have no clue at all where to start looking for an answer to this: I followed the instructions [here](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#install_on_debian_ubuntu) to set up nginx and passenger for debian. (`sudo apt-get nginx-extras passenger`) Everything worked fine. Then I tried to set up ssl:

- created a server key and so on
- copied /etc/nginx/sites-available/default and uncommented and edited the necessary lines
- created a symbolic link in /etc/nginx/sites-enable
- restarted nginx

Suddenly I couldn't connect to the server via firefox anymore. So I undid every above mentioned step - nothing. I uninstalled nginx-extras and passenger and manually removed every file and directory named '*nginx*' because I saw that the whole /etc/nginx/ directory still existed. I then installed everything again - still nothing.

Even when I thought it was completely removed `ps waux | grep nginx` produced this though:
`USERNAME 3776  0.0  0.1  11292   928 pts/0    S+   22:15   0:00 grep nginx`

Any ideas?

nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Phusion Passenger config
        ##
        # Uncomment it if you installed passenger or passenger-enterprise
        ##

        passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
        passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

default

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        index index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        #server_name localhost;
        server_name MYSERVERNAME.COM;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }

        location /doc/ {
                alias /usr/share/doc/;
                autoindex on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                allow ::1;
                deny all;
        }
     }
}
```

error.log

```
2013/12/18 21:26:11 [info] 4051#0: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for push module in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:73
[ 2013-12-18 21:26:11.5154 4052/7f52e36b2720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:510 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'nogroup', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/usr/bin/ruby', 'default_user' => 'nobody', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini', 'passenger_version' => '4.0.29', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_passenger_version' => '4.0.29', 'web_server_pid' => '4051', 'web_server_type' => 'nginx', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '33', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '33' }
[ 2013-12-18 21:26:11.5256 4055/7f9d793ff720 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:625 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.4051/generation-0/request
[ 2013-12-18 21:26:11.5422 4060/7f356bd97740 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:318 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.4051/generation-0/logging
[ 2013-12-18 21:26:11.5425 4052/7f52e36b2720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:697 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
[ 2013-12-18 21:26:12.6104 4085/7fd382f9e720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:510 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'nogroup', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/usr/bin/ruby', 'default_user' => 'nobody', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini', 'passenger_version' => '4.0.29', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_passenger_version' => '4.0.29', 'web_server_pid' => '4084', 'web_server_type' => 'nginx', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '33', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '33' }
[ 2013-12-18 21:26:12.6212 4088/7f366efae720 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:625 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.4084/generation-0/request
[ 2013-12-18 21:26:12.6372 4093/7fe9334f6740 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:318 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.4084/generation-0/logging
[ 2013-12-18 21:26:12.6376 4085/7fd382f9e720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:697 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
2013/12/18 21:29:14 [info] 4342#0: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for push module in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:73
2013/12/18 21:43:58 [info] 3268#0: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for push module in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:73
[ 2013-12-18 21:43:58.9454 3269/7ffca390a720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:510 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'nogroup', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/usr/bin/ruby', 'default_user' => 'nobody', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini', 'passenger_version' => '4.0.29', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_passenger_version' => '4.0.29', 'web_server_pid' => '3268', 'web_server_type' => 'nginx', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '33', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '33' }
[ 2013-12-18 21:43:58.9565 3272/7ff05712f720 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:625 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.3268/generation-0/request
[ 2013-12-18 21:43:59.0637 3277/7fd1a6566740 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:318 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.3268/generation-0/logging
[ 2013-12-18 21:43:59.0641 3269/7ffca390a720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:697 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
[ 2013-12-18 21:44:00.1272 3302/7f36e741a720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:510 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'nogroup', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/usr/bin/ruby', 'default_user' => 'nobody', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini', 'passenger_version' => '4.0.29', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_passenger_version' => '4.0.29', 'web_server_pid' => '3301', 'web_server_type' => 'nginx', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '33', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '33' }
[ 2013-12-18 21:44:00.1371 3305/7f39a4c0a720 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:625 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.3301/generation-0/request
[ 2013-12-18 21:44:00.1516 3310/7f77ac1f2740 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:318 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.3301/generation-0/logging
[ 2013-12-18 21:44:00.1519 3302/7f36e741a720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:697 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
2013/12/18 22:33:42 [info] 4446#0: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for push module in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:73
[ 2013-12-18 22:33:42.5973 4447/7f9322eec720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:510 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'nogroup', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/usr/bin/ruby', 'default_user' => 'nobody', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini', 'passenger_version' => '4.0.29', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_passenger_version' => '4.0.29', 'web_server_pid' => '4446', 'web_server_type' => 'nginx', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '33', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '33' }
[ 2013-12-18 22:33:42.6076 4450/7f4b5421a720 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:625 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.4446/generation-0/request
[ 2013-12-18 22:33:42.6231 4455/7f66ad0d7740 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:318 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.4446/generation-0/logging
[ 2013-12-18 22:33:42.6235 4447/7f9322eec720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:697 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
[ 2013-12-18 22:33:42.6937 4478/7f2efc258720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:510 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'nogroup', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/usr/bin/ruby', 'default_user' => 'nobody', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini', 'passenger_version' => '4.0.29', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_passenger_version' => '4.0.29', 'web_server_pid' => '4469', 'web_server_type' => 'nginx', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '33', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '33' }
[ 2013-12-18 22:33:42.7052 4481/7f22f972e720 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:625 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.4469/generation-0/request
[ 2013-12-18 22:33:42.7225 4486/7f115cf78740 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:318 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.4469/generation-0/logging
[ 2013-12-18 22:33:42.7229 4478/7f2efc258720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:697 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
2013/12/18 22:55:00 [info] 4571#0: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for push module in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:73
[ 2013-12-18 22:55:00.2297 4572/7fd2593b7720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:510 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'nogroup', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/usr/bin/ruby', 'default_user' => 'nobody', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini', 'passenger_version' => '4.0.29', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_passenger_version' => '4.0.29', 'web_server_pid' => '4571', 'web_server_type' => 'nginx', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '33', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '33' }
[ 2013-12-18 22:55:00.2402 4575/7fc908843720 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:625 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.4571/generation-0/request
[ 2013-12-18 22:55:00.2552 4580/7fc3a8488740 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:318 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.4571/generation-0/logging
[ 2013-12-18 22:55:00.2556 4572/7fd2593b7720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:697 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
[ 2013-12-18 22:55:01.3489 4607/7fdb92fa0720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:510 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'nogroup', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/usr/bin/ruby', 'default_user' => 'nobody', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini', 'passenger_version' => '4.0.29', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_passenger_version' => '4.0.29', 'web_server_pid' => '4606', 'web_server_type' => 'nginx', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '33', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '33' }
[ 2013-12-18 22:55:01.3590 4610/7fd6ff47d720 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:625 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.4606/generation-0/request
[ 2013-12-18 22:55:01.3746 4615/7f6beae3b740 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:318 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.4606/generation-0/logging
[ 2013-12-18 22:55:01.3750 4607/7fdb92fa0720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:697 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
2013/12/18 23:03:27 [info] 4735#0: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for push module in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:73
[ 2013-12-18 23:03:27.9453 4736/7fb2f8b7b720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:510 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'nogroup', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/usr/bin/ruby', 'default_user' => 'nobody', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini', 'passenger_version' => '4.0.29', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_passenger_version' => '4.0.29', 'web_server_pid' => '4735', 'web_server_type' => 'nginx', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '33', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '33' }
[ 2013-12-18 23:03:27.9556 4739/7f8d97b36720 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:625 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.4735/generation-0/request
[ 2013-12-18 23:03:27.9710 4744/7fb89953a740 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:318 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.4735/generation-0/logging
[ 2013-12-18 23:03:27.9714 4736/7fb2f8b7b720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:697 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
2013/12/18 23:36:45 [info] 5207#0: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for push module in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:73
[ 2013-12-18 23:36:45.0369 5208/7f9b67fc1720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:510 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'nogroup', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/usr/bin/ruby', 'default_user' => 'nobody', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini', 'passenger_version' => '4.0.29', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_passenger_version' => '4.0.29', 'web_server_pid' => '5207', 'web_server_type' => 'nginx', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '33', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '33' }
[ 2013-12-18 23:36:45.0474 5211/7fc05a851720 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:625 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.5207/generation-0/request
[ 2013-12-18 23:36:45.0637 5216/7ffc716ae740 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:318 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.5207/generation-0/logging
[ 2013-12-18 23:36:45.0641 5208/7f9b67fc1720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:697 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
[ 2013-12-18 23:36:46.1591 5243/7f29a6ba9720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:510 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'nogroup', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/usr/bin/ruby', 'default_user' => 'nobody', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini', 'passenger_version' => '4.0.29', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_passenger_version' => '4.0.29', 'web_server_pid' => '5242', 'web_server_type' => 'nginx', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '33', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '33' }
[ 2013-12-18 23:36:46.1697 5246/7f91dc2c2720 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:625 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.5242/generation-0/request
[ 2013-12-18 23:36:46.1861 5251/7f49ec0d4740 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:318 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.5242/generation-0/logging
[ 2013-12-18 23:36:46.1865 5243/7f29a6ba9720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:697 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
2013/12/18 23:55:06 [info] 5645#0: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for push module in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:73
[ 2013-12-18 23:55:06.5135 5646/7f89b653f720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:510 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'nogroup', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/usr/bin/ruby', 'default_user' => 'nobody', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini', 'passenger_version' => '4.0.29', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_passenger_version' => '4.0.29', 'web_server_pid' => '5645', 'web_server_type' => 'nginx', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '33', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '33' }
[ 2013-12-18 23:55:06.5237 5649/7f25f91cc720 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:625 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.5645/generation-0/request
[ 2013-12-18 23:55:06.5386 5654/7f470908c740 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:318 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.5645/generation-0/logging
[ 2013-12-18 23:55:06.5390 5646/7f89b653f720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:697 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
[ 2013-12-18 23:55:07.6364 5681/7f482aa8a720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:510 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'nogroup', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/usr/bin/ruby', 'default_user' => 'nobody', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini', 'passenger_version' => '4.0.29', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_passenger_version' => '4.0.29', 'web_server_pid' => '5680', 'web_server_type' => 'nginx', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '33', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '33' }
[ 2013-12-18 23:55:07.6472 5684/7fdd6c28b720 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:625 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.5680/generation-0/request
[ 2013-12-18 23:55:07.6631 5689/7f5d80851740 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:318 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.5680/generation-0/logging
[ 2013-12-18 23:55:07.6634 5681/7f482aa8a720 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:697 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
```

Comment: Sounds like it's starting up and then immediately bailing out. This is what nginx will do if something is wrong. Have you checked your defined log files (especially `/var/log/nginx/error.log`) or your system log?

Answer (score 1):

> I uninstalled nginx-extras and passenger and manually removed every file and directory named 'nginx' because I saw that the whole /etc/nginx/ directory still existed.

That's expected (and desirable).  The package manager won't delete your config files in /etc.

> Even when I thought it was completely removed ps waux | grep nginx produced this though: USERNAME 3776 0.0 0.1 11292 928 pts/0 S+ 22:15 0:00 grep nginx

Right.  That grep is detecting the grep command itself in the process list, since it contains "nginx".  I don't see anything in there that implies nginx is running.

Recommendations:

1. Reinstall nginx-extras and passenger, re-doing the configuration in /etc/nginx that you deleted.
2. Run `sudo service nginx status` to ensure it's still running.  If not:
3. Run `sudo service nginx start` or `sudo service nginx restart` and post any error messages it reports back.

Please post the (sanitized) the contents of your config files with your question. It helps a lot to know what configuration has been done, as I expect your problem is going to be fixed in those config files.

Comment: Did what you recommended and `sudo service nginx status` says `[ ok ] nginx is running.` - still nothing. I didn't alter nginx.conf much. Just uncommented passenger_root and passenger_ruby. I will edit in the whole file nonetheless.

Comment: As root, run `netstat -tnlp | grep nginx` to display what processes are listening on port 80.  It should look something like:

    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      18266/nginx

If it doesn't, nginx is not listening on port 80.

I don't recall offhand what the Debian default configs look like, but generally you need to do more than just uncomment the passenger paths to get it working.

Comment: `netstat -tnlp | grep nginx` returns nothing

Comment: Did you run it as root?  Non-root users (and on some systems even when run via sudo) netstat -p won't show the process using the port.  alternately, try running it without the grep to see all processes listening on ports: `sudo netstat -tnlp`  If you don't see process names, then you're not running it as root.

Comment: Have you run `sudo service nginx restart`?  What does it say when you do?

Comment: `sudo service nginx restart` just returns `[ ok ] Restarting nginx: nginx.`

I did `ln -s [...]/sites-available/default [...]/sites-enabled/default` though and now netstat returns what you said it would. Still - "Server not found". Furthermore: This already worked. When I installed it the first time...

Comment: OK, so nginx is listening on 80.  What are the contents of `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`?  I suspect the daemon is running but is missing a valid `server { ... }` directive and doesn't know where to look for the webroot.

What do the nginx logs say?  Any error messages in there when you hit it with a browser?

Comment: Uhm, theres no file at all in /etc/nginx/conf.d/; I edited in the contents of default; error.log too, but it doesn't do anything when trying to connect via firefox.